# How to make two images of same size?

Tags: matlab

I have two images with same dimension but different size how do i make them of equal size so that i can subtract then below is the description of my images

```
 d=imread('dif5.jpg');

>> f=size(d);

>> f

f = 900        1200           3

g=ndims(d);

>> g

g = 3

>> h=imread('dif4.jpg');

>> j=size(h);

>> j

j = 363   484     3

>> k=ndims(h);

>> k

k = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to [resample](http://www.mathworks.se/help/signal/ref/resample.html) the image; The Signal Processing Toolbox contains an implementation -- and also probably a ready made function targeted for images.

Off the top of my head (haven't tested):

```
a = resample(f, 900, 363)'; %% should produce 1200 x 363 x 3 (transposed) image
b = resample(b, 1200, 484)'; %% produces 363 x 484 x 3 image

c = b - h;  %% diff of the resampled image and the smaller image
```

Also [implementations](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22443-image-resampling) of bilinear, bicubic etc. using only standard functions are available:

Comment: If this doesn't work, please try to experiment with 1-D vectors first to e.g. resample `[1 2 3 4 5]` to a vector of 3, (5) or 10 elements. The function `resample` should be able to deal with matrices too, resampling along the columns.

Answer (score 0):

This is the job for which [`imresize`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html) is designed.

```
d = imread('dif5.jpg'); % 900 x 1200 x 3
h = imread('dif4.jpg'); % 363 x 484 x 3
dh = imresize(h,[size(d,1) size(d,2)],'bicubic'); % or 'linear', etc.
diffImg = dh - d; % 900 x 1200 x 3
```

Comment: I tried it..but now i am getting error called matrix dimension must agree

Comment: What are `size(dh)` and `size(d)`?